# Batch File SET variable issue

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create which when conditions are met will go to certain threads.

```
:question_generate
cls
set question_value = %random%
if /i %question_value% LSS 100 goto q1
if /i %question_value% LSS 200 goto q2
goto question_generate
```

It seems correctly coded but i can' t find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *not* have spaces in your `set` command, the spaces after the variable become part of the variable name:

```
c:\pax> set qq = %random%

c:\pax> echo %qq%
%qq%

c:\pax> echo %qq %
21573

c:\pax> set qq=%random%

c:\pax> echo %qq%
15121

c:\pax> set q
qq=15121
qq = 21573
```

In your case, you have created a variable called "`question_valueSPACE`" but you're *testing* the one "`question_value`".